# Jquery Jtable align fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How to make the fields center aligned in jtable. I want to make the the last field(Stacks:) center aligned

```
fields: {
    ID: {
      key: true,
      create: false,
      edit: false,
      list: false
    },
    TID: {
      title: 'Type',
      width: '30%',
      inputClass: 'validate[required]',
      options: <%= DisplayCribOptions() %>
    },
    Number: {
      title: 'Crib No',
      width: '20%'
    },
    Name: {
      title: 'Name',
      width: '20%'
    },
    Stacks: {
      title: 'Configurable Stacks',
      width: '30%'
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the listClass property to add your own style to fields.

```
Stacks: {
      title: 'Configurable Stacks',
      width: '30%',
       listClass: 'Stacksalign'

    }
```

Define your style in a class

```
.Stacksalign
{
    text-align: center;
}
```